# Thinkpad x61 with Mint 19.1 connecting to TV but NOT to projector

Tags: drivers, display

I have a [Thinkpad x61](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/lenovo-thinkpad-x61-review/) that I plan on using to teach at university.  It comes with a tablet screen and stylus.  When using Xournal, it allows me to write notes and create narrations very effectively!

I currently run Linux Mint 19.1 (with MATE and xfce) on it.  I have experimented with a bootable USB with Raspbian also.  Both these OS's work just fine: in that, I am able to do my regular work, use the tablet interface and connect it using VGA (or VGA-HDMI adapter) to my television.

**The problem arises** when I try to connect this laptop to the university projector systems (either Epson or NEC LT 380).  I am **never** able to mirror the screen via the projector to a screen.  This issue defeats the purpose of using my Thinkpad x61 with linux.  *I suspect it is a driver issue*.  I do not want to have to go buy a Windows tablet just becase this may not have such issues.

This is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 0c)
```

Output of `inxi -Fxz` is:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
       bus-ID: 00:02.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6
       drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
       Resolution: 1024x768@76.00hz
       OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)
       version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Render: Yes
```

I have only included what seem to be graphics/display related items.

Is there a solution to this?  Should I be updating my drivers?  If so, how should I best proceed?  When I compare with other laptops I have (which run Linux mint 18 or 19 or Ubuntu), they have `rev 09` instead of `rev 0c`.

If any more info is needed, please let me know and I will gladly update this question.

Comment: In order to debug this issue: the whole driver doesn't seem to be a problem, because otherwise the connection with your home TV wouldn't work neither, right?. Maybe is a problem with certain resolutions :/ One of the projectors you mention, could be this one?: http://www.nec-pj.com/products/lt/index380.html If so, I see that it can display in a resolution of 1024x768. Can you try that resolution with your "working device" (meaning your TV) for example, and share the results?.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried with the TV.  The display is NOT mirrored anymore! I don't know what is wrong now.

Comment: @txapelgorri  I may have found a solution... see my answer.  Thank you for your insightful input.

Answer (score 0):

I found *one solution*.  The following resources were useful to arrive at this conclusion:

[How to set Display Resolution while having to use “NOMODESET” on boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/761149/41821)

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38780/41821)

Basically, after startup, I navigated to `/etc/default` and editted the grub file via `sudo vim grub`.  In the grub file, I **removed** the keyword `nomodeset`.

After this, I saved the grub file and ran `sudo update-grub`.

On restart, all screen resolutions were now available to me.  The laptop now worked with my television.  I will be checking with projectors on-campus later.